# How to DM the host of the giveaway when their giveaway ended

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm using the [Discord Giveaways](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-giveaways) module.

I would like to know how to DM the host of the giveaway when their giveaway ended. I don't quite know how to do it yet.

This is what I know:

```js
manager.on('giveawayEnded', (giveaway, winners) => {
     winners.forEach((member) => {
         member.send('Congratulations, '+member.user.username+', you won: '+giveaway.prize);
     });
});
```

The code above shows how to DM the winner of the giveaway, I found that code in [the docs](https://discord-giveaways.js.org/GiveawaysManager.html#event:giveawayEnded) but there was no code on how to dm the owner.

```js
 bot.giveawaysManager.giveaways.filter((g) => g.ended);
```

The code above shows how to filter the ended giveaways

```js
bot.giveawaysManager.start(message.channel, {
                time: ms(giveawayDuration),
                prize: giveawayPrize,
                winnerCount: giveawayWinners,
                hostedBy: message.author,
            })
```

The code above shows how to make the giveaway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you receive a `giveaway` object when the `giveawayEnded` is fired. If it has a `prize` property, I'm pretty sure it also has a `hostedBy` property.

`hostedBy` is a "mention string" (e.g. `<@335657562220537971>`), you can get the user's ID from it using [`.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice), then fetch the user. Once you've fetched them, you can simply DM them:

```js
manager.on('giveawayEnded', async (giveaway, winners) => {
  const hostID = giveaway.hostedBy.slice(2, -1);
  const host = await client.users.fetch(hostID);

  if (host) {
    host.send('Giveaway ended');
  }

  winners.forEach((member) => {
    member.send(
      'Congratulations, ' +
        member.user.username +
        ', you won: ' +
        giveaway.prize,
    );
  });
});
```